# Magento discount to multiple categories without discounting SKU?

Tags: php, magento

I am applying a price rule to whole categories in my Magento store but I want to leave out a few of the items within the discounted category.

How can I do this in the price rules?
I have tried everything and it just discounts all the products and still discounts the products I want to leave at full normal price.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with Shopping Cart price rules.

In the Actions section, under "apply the rule to the items matching this criteria":

[image]